# How to remove entity type from drush?

Tags: drush, entities

How do I remove an entity type via drush?

List of entity types I can get via:

```
drush eval 'print_r(array_keys(entity_get_info()));'

Array
(
    [0] => node
    [1] => taxonomy_term
    [2] => comment
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity types can't be generically deleted. First of all, *node* is entity type and can't be deleted using `node_type_delete`. You can only delete content type - and that's a *bundle* of entity called *node*.

To delete bundles that belongs to other modules, module providing entity type needs to provide drush command to delete bundle. You will find that command in module's documentation. And to remove entity type altogether, you need to disable and uninstall module that provides said entity type.

[An Introduction to Entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261744) may be a good read for you now. I advise caution, because it's status is "Needs technical review", but it covers basics nicely.

Comment: He meant "bundles"

Comment: Entity type returned by `entity_get_info()`.

Comment: @Clive I'm not so sure about it. Does his recent comment under my answer and edit to his question confirm your statement?

Comment: @kernob I think you should edit your question to clarify what you're asking - `node_type_delete()` is not for deleting an entity type, it's for removing a _type_, or bundle, of nodes (e.g. the article content type). There's no such concept as deleting an entity type, as they only exist in code. Remove the code that defines them (i.e. uninstall the providing module), and the entity type will disappear. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @kernob. The answer is "you cannot" in this case, not via drush, not via the UI, not via an API function. The concept of deleting core entity types on required core modules is not something you can realise with Drupal 7

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm asking because I've weird situation where entity type was not removed during disabling/removing the module. I've tried `drush -y cc entity`, but it didn't remove it either. And when clearing the all caches, it breaks because some hook_menu() relies on entity_get_info() which still having the old information about the entities and the clear cache in this case not removing the faulty entity and generates [PDOException](https://www.drupal.org/node/2208271).

Answer (score 1):

Entity types are provided by the modules ([hook_entity_info](https://api.drupal.org/hook_entity_info)), therefore the only way to remove them is to disable and uninstall the appropriate module.

---

**Troubleshooting**

- The following drush command finds the invalid entity types:

  ```
  drush eval 'foreach (entity_get_info() as $entity_type => $entity_info) { !isset($entity_info[label], $entity_info[bundles]) && var_dump($entity_type, $entity_info); };'
  ```
- If you already disabled and uninstalled module and entity is still there, check if other modules (or custom code) are not using or referencing to it (e.g. [hook_entity_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/hook_entity_info_alter), views, fields, features, etc.).
- Rebuild the entities and caches via drush:

  ```
  drush eval "entity_defaults_rebuild();"
  drush -y cc entity
  killall -HUP memcached # If you're using memcached.
  drush -y cc all
  ```